# Dynamically making slots of Day in Angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I need to Dynamically make different slots of the day of such that--

1. Monday

   Slot 1: 9:00AM - 11:00AM
    Slot 2: 2:00PM - 4:00Pm
    Slot 3: 6:00PM - 11:00PM
2. Tuesday

   Slot 1: 10:00AM - 11:00AM
    Slot 2: 1:00PM - 5:00Pm
    Slot 3: 7:00PM - 11:00PM
3. Friday

   Slot 1: 8:00AM - 11:00AM
    Slot 2: 12:00PM- 1:00PM
    Slot 3: 3:00PM - 4:00Pm
    Slot 4: 9:00PM - 11:00PM

Here the available days of weeks are flexible as well as the No. of slots along with the timing of the Slots also dynamic.
I need a suitable Data Structure to store these variables so that I can Implement it in Angularjs.
Should I use array for each or there may be some better way to implement it.

I have tried to use array as

```
[ "available days": {"Monday":["Slot 1: 9:00AM - 11:00AM", "Slot 2: 2:00PM - 4:00Pm", "Slot 3: 6:00PM - 11:00PM"]}, 
{"Tuesday":["Slot 1: 10:00AM - 11:00AM", "Slot 2: 1:00PM - 5:00Pm", "Slot 3: 7:00PM - 11:00PM"]},
 {"Friday":["Slot 1: 8:00AM - 11:00AM", "Slot 2: 12:00PM- 1:00PM", "Slot 3: 3:00PM - 4:00Pm", "Slot 4: 9:00PM - 11:00PM"]}]
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have mentioned that I have tried to implement using array as data structure

Comment: Letting us see what kind of operations you need to this data structure would be helpful. And JSON format you've tried might be broken.

Answer (score 1):

It's Very Easy. Get JSON as a list in the controller and assign it to a $scope that is nothing but the ng-model like,

```
$scope.slots=[ "available days": {"Monday":["Slot 1: 9:00AM - 11:00AM", 
 "Slot 2: 2:00PM - 4:00Pm", "Slot 3: 6:00PM - 11:00PM"]},
    {"Tuesday":["Slot 1: 10:00AM - 11:00AM", "Slot 2: 1:00PM - 5:00Pm", "Slot 3: 7:00PM - 11:00PM"]},
   {"Friday":["Slot 1: 8:00AM - 11:00AM", "Slot 2: 12:00PM- 1:00PM", "Slot 3: 3:00PM - 4:00Pm", "Slot 4: 9:00PM - 11:00PM"]}];
```

Now get the objects one by one based on the current timing from the date format.
Later check the name of the slot in the array using angulat.forEach() condition

```
angular.forEach($scope.slots,function(list){
// code goes here....
})
```

Now in that check the condition and assign it to the another $scope as ng-model, and ng-repeat in the html that particular list of condition.

Note: You have to get the list of ng-repeat as

```
ng-repeat="item in slotlist.available days"
```

Here slotlist is your newly assigned ng-model and available days is you array in which data is available.